# Ajax callback is only called once on final iteration of loop

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback

[EDIT] new question about the callback [edit]

I am trying to load some local text files using Ajax and Javascript, but I cannot get the callback to work properly.
I have an outline of my code:

```
 var theFiles = {
  one: null,
  two: null,
  three: null,
  four: null,
  five: null,
  six: null,
  seven: null
};
function callback(pos,arrayofwords) {

    theFiles[pos]=arrayofwords;
}

xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

var getFiles = function(theFiles,callback) {
  for (var p in theFiles) {
    console.log("in getFile: " + p);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {

        callback(p,xhr.responseText.split(/\r?\n/));
      }
     };

    xhr.open("GET", p + ".txt", true);
    xhr.send();
  }
}
```

Stored locally are the files one.txt, two.txt, three.txt etc...
The callback is only executed once even though the for loop calls an open() for each key in theFiles. Only the last item in theFiles (seven) is populated.
I don't understand why.

UPDATE
After being provided the answer by @xianshenglu I have discovered that the callback is actually not needed. This works as well

```
    var theFiles = {
  one: null,
  two: null,
  three: null,
  four: null,
  five: null,
  six: null,
  seven: null
};



var getFiles = function(theFiles) {
  for (let p in theFiles) {   //var to let
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();  //move inside the loop
    console.log("in getFile: " + p);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {

        theFiles[p]=xhr.responseText.split(/\r?\n/)); //no callback needed
      }
     };

    xhr.open("GET", p + ".txt", true);
    xhr.send();
  }
}
```

Comment: Read [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48716385/ajax-callback-is-only-called-once-on-final-iteration-of-loop/48716660#48716660), I explained **what** you should to do and **why**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
var getFiles = function(theFiles, callback) {
    for (let p in theFiles) {
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        console.log("in getFile: " + p);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);//test if work;
                callback(p, xhr.responseText.split(/\r?\n/));
            }
        };

        xhr.open("GET", p + ".txt", true);
        xhr.send();
    }
};
```

explanation:

If you take an xhr object that's busy sending and receiving and tell it to send another request, it simply stops doing whatever it does and sends out the new request.

another explanation about var :

```js
function f(a) {
  console.log(a);
}
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  document.body.onclick = function() {
    f(i)
  };
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

click body three times,you will always get 3,the last value;so,don't use var in loop,because code above almost equals to :

```
function f(a) {
  console.log(a);
}
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  document.body.onclick = function() {
    f(i);// not execute at once,when executing ,i already becomes the last one,which is 3;
  };
}
```

for more information,do some research about var hoisting,you will get a lot,[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)

Comment: thank you.. it is calling the callback for each time through the loop now but each time the value of 'p' is 'seven' the last value only.

Comment: what about the xhr.responseText ,is this the last one?

Comment: every iteration of the loop the xhr.responseText has the correct file but in the onreadystatechange function the value of p is always 'seven' the last one.

Comment: @user2250892 let p in theFiles,did you use var p in theFiles?

Comment: @user2250892,when you use var ,it get the last one ,if you let ,it works right,i tested

Comment: yes, it works with let... a big gap in my understanding here as I have no idea why that is so.. anyway thanks!

Comment: @user2250892,add some explanation about var ,check to see

Comment: Interestingly after changing the var to let in the for loop I don't even need to use the callback! I can replace the callback with theFiles[p]=xhr.responseText.split(/\r?\n/); and it works.. no callback required .

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, using async/await and fetch.

```
let getFile = async (p) => {
    console.log("in getFile: " + p);
    let res = await fetch('/' + p + '.txt');
    let text = await res.text();
    return text.split(/\r?\n/);
}

let getFiles = async () => {
    for (let p in theFiles) theFiles[p] = await getFile(p);
}

getFiles();
```

More on [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)/[await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

Answer (score 0):

**You should use `let` instead of `var`.**

> If you use **let** instead of **var** it will work **because:**
>
> `for` loop run very fast *(before running ajax)* so if you use `var` in
>   `for (var p in theFiles)`, the `p` value will be override in each
>   iteration of the loop and finally filled with last value of
>   `theFiles`, now ajax operations will be started and all of them use `p` and `p`
>   is filled with last item of `theFiles`.
>
> **But** if we use **let** instead of var each `p` will be different
>   than another `p` in the iterations of the loop. So it works well.